# Accessing Apple's root certificate on iOS

Tags: ios, security, openssl, certificate, keychain

I've found the following code: https://github.com/roddi/ValidateStoreReceipt/blob/master/validatereceipt.m which loads the root certificate ('Apple Root CA') on MacOS

and I'm trying to make it work on iOS as well.

Our code is written in C++ and uses OpenSSL for validating a remote peer when using SSL sockets.

On other platforms, we load the root certificate and add them to the context using **X509_STORE_add_cert**.

We then use **SSL_get_peer_certificate** and verify the hostname. These are NOT self-signed certificates which is why we want to use the root certificate of the device.

My question is how to get the root certificate on iOS devices?

EDIT:

I've tried the following query, but I keep getting -25300 (errSecItemNotFound).

```
NSDictionary* query=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,kSecClass,
                     kCFBooleanTrue,kSecReturnRef,
                     kSecMatchLimitAll,kSecMatchLimit,
                     kCFBooleanTrue,kSecMatchTrustedOnly,
                     nil];
SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query,&ref);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want something along these lines:

- Find the certificates using `SecItemCopyMatching()` with `kSecMatchTrustedOnly` set to `kCFBooleanTrue`. Remember, this will be [a lot of certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5012), not just one.
- Then export them to DER format with `SecCertificateCopyData()`.
- Import them into OpenSSL
- Profit

Alternately, you can go the other way:

- Convert certificate to DER using OpenSSL
- Create a `SecCertificateRef` with `SecCertificateCreateWithData()`
- Create a `SecPolicyRef` with `SecPolicyCreateSSL()`
- Create a `SecTrustRef` with `SecTrustCreateWithCertificates()`
- Evaluate with `SecTrustEvaluate()`
- Profit

Or of course you could also manage the SSL connection with `NSURLConnection` or with `CFNetwork` (available directly in C++) and the system would do everything for you automatically. Whenever possible, I recommend against using OpenSSL on iOS because it creates a lot of complexity. But the above should help you bridge if you need to.

Comment: I've tried that, but I don't get any matches (check my edit).

Comment: I'm sorry; had Mac OS X on the brain. In iOS you don't have access to any keychain except your application keychain. So you can't get the list of certificates from the device. You can use the list I linked (HT5012) to find what's normally on the device, but it doesn't give the full cert. Typically you don't want "any" root anyway, you just want the root for your certs, so you can ship those directly. But otherwise, you can export the certs from a Mac and ship them with your product, or you can use the second approach above.

Comment: The problem is that the user won't connect to my server but to other servers and I want to verify whether it has a valid SSL certificate (which I can't predict upfront which is why I want to validate against the root certificate). Anyway, I think I'm going to try the second approach and switch my code to use native calls when possible which will take care of the SSL verification for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to distribute certificates. Using email - send certificate as an attachment, tapping on it will start the installation process. Or using browser - navigate Safari to the page that hosts your certificate, download it and install. You can also use configuration profiles to streamline deployment.

Read more about it in [iPad in Business](http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/pdf/iPad_Deployment_Scenarios.pdf), scroll down to `Distributing and Installing Certificates` section.

**EDIT**: certificate lookup

To find a keychain item you can use [SecItemCopyMatching](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemCopyMatching) providing `kSecClassCertificate` and `kSecAttrLabel`. Checkout [Finding a Certificate In the Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW2) in [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Tasks for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html)

Comment: I'm aware how to load a supplied certificate, my question was how to load the EXISTING root certificate. I do not wish to bundle a certificate with my app, I want to use Apple's one.

Comment: I misinterpreted your question. See if my edit about `SecItemCopyMatching` can help you.

Comment: I've tried that, but I don't get any matches (check my edit).